# Disable asp imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the image button in this table to get hidden via the code behind in C# (so that I can hide it after an action).

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upEmpListContainer" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    OnPreRender="upEmpListContainer_PreRender" OnInit="upEmpListContainer_Oninit">
    <ContentTemplate>

<asp:ListView ID="lvEmpList" OnItemDataBound="lvEmpList_ItemDataBound" OnDataBound="lvEmpList_DataBound"
            OnLayoutCreated="lvEmpList_LayoutCreated" runat="server" OnPreRender="lvEmpList_PreRender">
            <LayoutTemplate>
            <table class="formData_tb" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0px; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="9" class="currentManagerLabel" style="text-align: center">
                    <span>Currently displaying
                        <asp:Label ID="lblManager" runat="server" />
                        employees </span>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="DrillUp" AlternateText="Move up in reporting heirarchy" runat="server"
                        CommandName="DrillDown" ImageUrl="~/images/icoDoubleArrowUp.gif" OnCommand="butDrillDown_Click" />
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I just can't seem to access it from its ID. I've tried `DrillUp.Enabled = false;` but Visual Studio is saying that it can't resolve symbol 'DrillUp'.

Comment: Go to the designer file and see if `DrillUp` is declared over there. I am assuming you are having aspx in some dll, which sometime causes designer file to not get updated. If declaration is not there, try adding the image button again on the page or declare it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imagebutton is inside layout template, you cant access it directly.

Try this

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton)lvEmpList.FindControl("DrillUp");
b.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind method lvEmpList_ItemDataBound, you need to use the following:

```
((e.Item.FindControl("DrillUp")) as ImageButton).Visible = false;
```

Also, you should add a check that this is done only for the DataItem items like this:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    ((e.Item.FindControl("DrillUp")) as ImageButton).Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to:
1-remove that imagebutton from aspx
1-clean the solution
2- Write manually again that asp:imagebutton...

It will work fine